# Why compiller stills trhowing CA1062 once I validated public nullable parameter?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, ca1062

I just enabled FxCop Code Analyzers and, while fixing warnings this one could not be fixed:

CA1062: Validate arguments of public methods

```
        public static string SanitizeFileName(this string fileName)
        {
            if (fileName is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fileName));

            foreach (char c in System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars())
            {
                fileName = fileName.Replace(c, '_');
            }

            return fileName;
        }
```

[Compiller still throwing warning CA1062](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qd99C.png) accessing fileName

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it work if you change `is null` to `== null`? (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/676210/ca1016-does-not-recognize-checking-null-with-is.html)

Comment: Yep. That did the trick. Is there an explanation? Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the comments at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/676210/ca1016-does-not-recognize-checking-null-with-is.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CA1062 warning is a design warning ([CA1062: Validate arguments of public methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1062?view=vs-2019)), an externally visible method dereferences one of its reference arguments without verifying whether that argument is null, it will show this warning.

I have reproduced the problem on my side using your code, it seems that this issue is related to the `is` operator, after changing the `is` operator to "`==`", the warning disappears.

```
    public static string SanitizeFileName(this string fileName)
    {
        if (fileName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fileName));

        foreach (char c in System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars())
        {
            fileName = fileName.Replace(c, '_');
        }

        return fileName;
    }
```

Besides, according to the sample code in the CA1062 warning, if you want to check whether the string is null, you could use the following code:

```
    public void Validate(string input)
    {
        if (input == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));
        }
        if (input.Length != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(input);
        }
    }
```